# Is it good practice to make every const string be referenced?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, types, reference

Code A:

```
string a = "Hello World";

for (int i=0; i<1000000; ++i) 
     const string b = a;
```

Code B:

```
string a = "Hello World";

for (int i=0; i<1000000; ++i) 
     const string &b = a;
```

If I run the 2 codes separately and measure CPU time, the Code B was about 2.5 times faster than the Code A.

Except for the primitive types such as `char`, `int`, `float`... I learned it is faster to get a reference to the original rather than copying it.

Although the difference is almost neglectable in most cases, can it be considered as a good practice to always make `const string` type(and other non-primitive types) be referenced?

Comment: The usual guideline is the following. If a type has a `sizeof` that is larger than `sizeof(void*)`, then always pass by const reference, otherwise pass by copy. If you want to change the object then pass a non-const reference regardless of size.

Comment: There are exceptions--for instance if you want to make a copy of the argument in the function, then pass by value--it implicitly makes the copy you want, and can take advantage of things like move operations to do so efficiently.

Comment: Classes might define custom copy or assignment operators (as string does), so `sizeof` isn’t always a good indicator of copy time.

Comment: Not "every", you need to be sure that you use the refence(`b`) contained within the life time of referenced object(`a`)

Comment: It really depends on the use case but yes, if you just need to view the variable `const&` is a good way to do that.

Comment: Your compiler sucks. :) Neither code has any effect; it should reduce down to a `ret` instruction or whatever.

Comment: "can it be considered as a good practice to always ..." - don't be dogmatic - *always* is almost never the right rule. It's often a good idea, but it depends (as always).

Comment: @Kaz I bet he's been timing an un-optimized debug build (which is never really interresting anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is generally better to use a const reference for any object that is expensive to copy. But you must take care that the original object doesn't change when you don't expect it; in particular you need to make sure that the original object isn't destroyed, because that leads to undefined behavior. That isn't a problem in your toy example, but in the real world it's a big concern.

The best place to use a const reference is in function parameters. You *know* that the object passed into the function can't change or be destroyed while still inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things to take into account.

1. Your use case. Do you want to copy or do you want to observe?
2. Does the type perform deep-copy semantics (e.g. allocate dynamic memory on copy)?

***If you wish to merely observe the object***:
If the type of the object allocates dynamic memory on copy, then always pass by const reference.
Otherwise if the `sizeof` of the type is larger than `sizeof(void*)` then pass by const reference.
Otherwise pass by value.

***If you wish to copy the object***, then just pass by value.

Of course in a strange use case you may do something else, but this is the general guideline that I see is commonly followed.

There's also move semantics to take into account, but that's a different question.

Comment: You might also want to mention that for `std::string` there is `std::string_view` to observe the string in C++17.

Comment: And an interesting data point is that `sizeof(string_view)` is about `2*sizeof(void*)`, but `string_view` is passed by value in the C++17 standard library.

Comment: @BoPersson I was recently looking at the implementation of `std::any` in both `libcxx` and `stdlibc++`. In `libcxx` they consider a "small object" to be `3*sizeof(void*)` while in `stdlibc++` - `sizeof(void*)` instead. I found this quite interesting. It can also be found in the standard iterators which are passed by value. Some containers like `std::deque` on my platform have an iterator of size 32 bytes.